# Why mail is not working after installing app to another org?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

In my app, I have a feature which sends emials to leads. This is the code I used:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.toAddresses = new String[] { emailId };
message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
message.setSenderDisplayName(senderDisplay);
message.subject = emailSubject;
message.setHtmlBody(emailFinalBody);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

This code is working fine in my app. **But, after I create a managed package and installed this app on another org, this code is not working**. I have checked many times. Its not showing any errors or throwing exceptions, i am just not receiving the mail. I have checked the spam folders and other folders. Also, in the helper.js class from where I call this apex method, `response.getState()` is `SUCCESS`. Everything else seems to work fine. I just don't receive the email.

So, what could be the problem? Do I have to do something in the new org to enable email service? Or is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: On the subscriber org (i.e., another org), have you check 'Email Log Files' & 'Email Snapshots'? That may give you some clue.

Comment: is email deliverability enabled in the new org?